# Open a web page but clear any session while doing so

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to add a link on my web page but I want to make sure anyone that clicks it will not be logged in to the application immediately....

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.application.com', '_blank')">test</a>
```

Is there anyway I can leverage javascript to open a new session each time the link is clicked so the user has to enter their credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

New browser sessions can only be created by the user.

The only way to achieve this would be to change the authentication system so it stored the credentials inside the page, and then loaded fresh content with Ajax. Opening a new window would create a new page without the credentials associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything in BOM that allows for that, sorry.